# Changing an inputted integer into a defined constant value

Tags: c

I am new to programming (very new so sorry if this is a stupid question) and I was wondering how you change an int of a variable into a constant value in C e.g. if I was to input a month (in number form) to a variable 'month', then a function convertMonthToDays lets say would change that inputted integer into a corresponding constant. So 3 would be equal to MARCH which is a constant defined as 30.

Thank you

Comment: Too broad. Can you show some code please?

Comment: Maybe I am too stup** to undestand what you are asking.

Comment: I don't know, I tried making an int daysInMonth (int month) where month is the input month like 4 or something and then making daysInMonth (4) = APR where APR is defined as 30

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `const int`, instead of a `#define`. The const qualifier guarantees that the value will not be changed during the program's lifetime.

Now, for your particular example you can use an array of 12 const int values to define the number of days in a year:

```
const int daysInAMonth[12] = {30, 28, 31, 30...};
```

This way you use the index to retrieve the number of days in that month.

On a side note, this is not the most elegant way of getting the number of days in month because you still have the problem of the leap year. But I only answered the question you initially asked.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Nice, I was posting the same answer, I suggest to change `const int daysInAMonth[12] = {30, 28, 31, 30...};` to `const int daysInAMonth[13] = {0, 30, 28, 31, 30...};` because `january` is month #1

Comment: `So 3 would be equal to MARCH` and in your array `3` is april.

Comment: Currently for the assignment I am doing, I can't use anything I haven't learnt so I can't use an array.

Comment: @sparkyboomman than have 12 #defines : JAN 30, FEB 28..etc And call your function   convertMonthToDays(JAN). Can't really give you a better answer because there seem to be constraints to the problem you have not mentioned, and I can't guess...

Answer (score 0):

Constants are a compile-time idea in C (and most other languages).  The best you're going to be able to do is to assign a variable, probably global in your situation, and promise not to change it except in an "approved context," like when you get the user input.

It's ugly (nobody likes global variables), but it works.  In object-oriented languages, you can bundle your month variable with the code that *uses* it, and you can deny access to that "member variable."

But in C, you're on the honor system, except at compile time.

The next-best possibility (actually, a *better* approach, but further from what you're asking) would be to return your "days in a month" value from a function.  Since you can't rewrite the function at run-time, you can't change the result it returns.

Comment: even I have a though time trying to understand your answer and I kind of know what you are trying to explain....please rephrase it